# В PyCharm установлен пакет telebot. Как его можно удалить?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в командной строке виндовз пишу:
pip uninstall telebot
пишет, что не установлен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нашел совет. что надо установить pytelegrambotapi
пишу в командной:
pip install -U pytelegrambotapi
показывает, что пакеты загружены.

как мне удалить из PySharm из Python Interpreter telobot и проинсталировать туда pytelegrambotapi ?

Comment: минус нажать не пробовали?

Comment: убрать получилось. спасибо.

Comment: теперь вопрос, как поставить тот пакет, который нужен. я так понимаю, pytelegrambotapi

Comment: Плюс нажать не пробовали?

Comment: гениально! благодарю!

Answer (score 4):

Вам бы вообще разобраться, что происходит в IDE. В проекте подключен интерпретатор из виртуального окружения. На первом скрине `Project Interpreter` показывает его место расположения `C:\User\Константин\untitled1\venv\...`. В этом виртуальном окружении хранится как интерпретатор python, так и pip и все установленные пакеты.

На 2-м скрине в командной строке Вы выполняете команды глобально. Для того что бы взаимодействовать с виртуальным окружением, Вам либо полный путь до pip/python в команде указывать надо `<пути до venv>\bin\python -m pip uninstall <package>`, либо активировать его `source venv/bin/activate` и обращаться к pip/python как обычно, либо выполнять команды в терминале PyCharm(он внутри автоматически активирует виртуальное окружение)

Comment: благодарю! только в начале пути!